# Disaster recovery and programming in gwan

Tags: g-wan, disaster-recovery

How does gwan supports disaster recovery? If gwan gets down, how can it handle incoming requests?
Is gwan then highly available?

"If the G-WAN process crashes/freezes itself, then the parent process (kills a frozen child if any and then) restarts a new clean child process."

1. What does the child process in above line referring to?
2. How can parent process restarts a new child process, when it itself gets down?
3. Is the child process same as thread per physical CPU in G-WAN?
4. G-WAN does not have configuration file. It creates web sites, virtual Hosts & aliases by merely creating folders. How can this be possible? Where can we program then? What are G-WAN scripts and where they resides?

I searched a lot on internet but was unable to find anything relevant about how gwan has supported disaster recovery.

Please let me know.

Comment: I suggest you download G-WAN, have a look at its directory structures, and give it a try using `gwan` and `gwan -d` before asking further questions

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean *"what if a G-WAN script or the server itself crashes"*?

There's a detailled answer in the [G-WAN FAQs](http://gwan.ch/faq#healing).

Let me know if you have further questions or if it answers your question.